# Нанесение текста на gif-анимацию

Tags: php, gif

Здравствуйте, предстоит задача наносить копирайт(текст) на загружаемые изображения, но дело в том, что среди них и есть GIF-анимации разных размеров.

Поэтому 2 вопроса:

1. Для работы с GIF-анимацией какие функции в PHP используются? На каждый кадр, по-сути, нужно накладывать текст?
2. Как правильно располагать копирайт, ведь точные координаты можно указать лишь при одинаковом размере? Считывать размер изображения и отталкиваясь от этого наносить копирайт?

Спасибо за ответы.

Попробовал работать с графическими функциями пока - не выходит, берет первый слой с gif, наносит на него текст и на этом всё, остаётся вместо gif-анимации полностью её первый кадр.
Код:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/gif");
$string = "TEST";
$img  = imagecreatefromgif("test.gif");
$px = 5;
imagestring($img, 3, $px, 9, $string, 0);
imagegif($img);
imagedestroy($im);

?>
```

Comment: В свое время помогло вот [это](https://github.com/coldume/imagecraft)

Comment: @Venta, у меня не работает, увы. GD есть, PHP 4.0.

UPD: хотя нет, только вывод. Изображение сохранилось, попробую с другим сейчас.

Comment: А нет, всё сработало, спасибо Вам!

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, это то, что вам нужно (смотрите там есть примеры обработки gif) http://php.net/manual/ru/imagick.coalesceimages.php